# css rotating (looping?) through different animations

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found an awesome code pen of these responsive devices in css  that morph with the screen size, and for my class I am trying to manipulate them into changing on a timer.

This is what I'm talking about - http://codepen.io/hariawan/pen/mjbwy.

I basically am trying to get it to rotate through the different device animations without the screen size changing, and I'm wondering if I can do this in purely css.

My first Idea was to just swap classes with javascript,  with a setTimeout controlling the swapping. I'm wondering if something like this could be done purely with css? Maybe some kind of really slow keyframe that loops through all of them?

My first Idea was something like this :

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // change 1
     setTimeout(function() {
       // change 2
     }, 5000);
  }, 5000);
```

And so on, then inevitable linking back to the first device.  I don't think this method is the best way AND I think it would be easiest if i could do it entirely in css. Any insight would be very helpful. Thanks for reading!

Comment: You could do it only in css by using animations, but dealing with so many elements (6 elements) and trying to sync 6 animations for each device state (4 devices) is very hard and leads to messy code (6 animations with 6 steps each).  I personally like your initial approach and advise you to use css classes to define each device (instead of media query) and then change them either with a timer or by user interaction (such as keypress)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your response @gion_13 , I feel like javascript approach is probably easier. I guess I'm just curious If I could do it in pure css without a headache. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter version - http://jsfiddle.net/n0L3eouq/

```
timeout(0);
function timeout(ind) {
  var classes = ['desk', 'laptop', 'tablet', 'phone'];
  $('#device').removeClass(classes.join(' '))
              .addClass(classes[ind % classes.length]);
  setTimeout(function () { timeout(ind + 1); }, 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, based off of @gion_13 's answer, I made a javascript solution -

seen here : http://codepen.io/ajmajma/pen/JBrtw

Swapping the media query styles to their own class and adding a looping javascript timeout like so

```
   timeout();
function timeout() {

setTimeout(function () {

  if($("#device").hasClass("desk")){
       $("#device").removeClass("desk");
       $("#device").addClass("laptop");
     }else if($("#device").hasClass("laptop")){
       $("#device").removeClass("laptop");
       $("#device").addClass("tablet");
    }else if($("#device").hasClass("tablet")){
       $("#device").removeClass("tablet");
       $("#device").addClass("phone");
     }else if($("#device").hasClass("phone")){
       $("#device").removeClass("phone");
      $("#device").addClass("desk");
     }

    timeout();
}, 4000);
}
```